# "Missing message activity" warning

Tags: journeybuilder, error-messages, custom-activity, warning

I have created a new message custom activity that works fine

The config.json has a `"category":"message"` option and the package is registered as "message", but still upon validation the Journey Builder warns about not being a message activity in the journey

It doesn't prevent the journey activation

the validate route at the endpoint returns `res.status(200).send('Validate')`

[image: Missing Message Warning]

what can I do to make this warning not show up?